# How to solve "Null check operator used on a null value"-error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to add data from database on `List<String> _names = [];` element. so for that, I add my API response data to that list but when I tried to initialize that widget which stores the List item it gave an error of `Null check operator used on a null value` and I don't know what type of error is this I tried much time to resolve it but I can't.
I have a widget that stores the list of names and when I tried to add names on the empty list by Json response so I printed that list and it shows me the actual data which I want but when I initialize the widget it gave me an unnecessary error.

Here is my code:

```dart
  import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Swipers.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:swipe_cards/draggable_card.dart';
  import 'package:swipe_cards/swipe_cards.dart';
  import 'package:mindmatch/utils/widget_functions.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
  import 'dart:convert';
  import 'package:mindmatch/utils/Auth.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(CardApp());
}

class CardApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final double padding = 25;
    final sidePadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('Discover', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15,),),
  
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]
          ),
          ),
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: Padding(
              padding: sidePadding,
              child: MyHomePage(),
            ),
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var UsrID = Auth.prefs!.getString('usrid');
  var data;
  var usrpic = "";

  getData() async{
    var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/mm_api/index.php',{'act':'usrlists'}));
    data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      _names.add("${data[i]['fulname']}");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      _images.add("${data[i]['profimage']}");
    }

    print(_names);
    print(_images);
    setState(() {});
    print(res.body);
  }


  List<SwipeItem> _swipeItems = <SwipeItem>[];
  MatchEngine? _matchEngine;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  List<String> _names = [];
  List<String> _images = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _names.length; i++) {
      _swipeItems.add(SwipeItem(
        content: Content(text: _names[i], Swipeimage: _images[i]),
        likeAction: () {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
             content: Text("Liked ${_names[i]}"),
             duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ));
        },
        nopeAction: () {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Nope ${_names[i]}"),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ));
        },
        superlikeAction: () {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Superliked ${_names[i]}"),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ));
        },
        onSlideUpdate: (SlideRegion? region) async {
          print("Region $region");
        }
      ));
    }

    _matchEngine = MatchEngine(swipeItems: _swipeItems);
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final double padding = 25;
    final sidePadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding);

    return
      data != null? Stack(
        children: [
          NoMoreDataWidget(),
          SwipeCards(
            matchEngine: _matchEngine!,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                         begin: Alignment.topRight,
                         end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                         colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          child:
                          Image.network(
                            "https://www.*******.net/mm_api/files/profile/"+ _images[index],
                            height: 400,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children:[
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                                Text(
                                  _names[index],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 20
                                  ),
                                ),
                                addVerticalSpace(5),
                                Text(
                                  "Dieppe, Canada",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 15
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Persondetail()
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    'assets/images/Info.svg',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
            onStackFinished: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text("Stack Finished"),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              ));
            },
            itemChanged: (SwipeItem item, int index) {
              print("item: ${item.content.text}, index: $index");
            },
            upSwipeAllowed: true,
            fillSpace: true,
          ),
        ]
      ): const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    ;
  }
}

class NoMoreDataWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoMoreDataWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 150,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.error,
              size: 60.0,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Text(
              'No more data found.',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                color: Colors.grey[400],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So clearly add the code that I add `MyHomePage` class in main `CardApp` class but when I initialize it gave me an error `Null check operator used on a null value`.

Here is my error in the console:- [image: image of error in console]

Comment: The null check operator in question are the usage of `!`. By using that, you are telling Dart that the value will NEVER be `null` in this situation and it should just assume a non-null value. But Dart does never fully trust you, so it inserts a runtime null-check which is the one you are seeing failing since the value did end up being `null` even if you had promised that to never happen.

Comment: Please post at least the code that is causing the error. The line is clearly visible in the console, you could even click on it to get there. It is not in your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the `getData()` method is called after the for loop, therefore, the `_names` list is still empty when you are trying to access it. Also the `getData()` method is `async` and you're not waiting for the data to be fully loaded.